# Nested loop:inner loop is skipped once when executed

Tags: c

```
    int t,r,c;
    int matrix[100][100][100];
    int i,j,k=0,l=0;
    int te,ck=0;
    scanf("%d",&t);
    for(te=0;te<t;te++)
    {
            printf("RC");
            scanf("%d %d",&r, &c);
            for(i=0;i<r;i++)
            {
                    for(j=0;j<c;j++)
                    {
                            printf("te= %d i= %d j= %d",te,i,j);
                            fflush(stdin);
                            matrix[te][i][j] = getchar();
                    }
            }
    }
```

sample o/p

```
abhi@ubuntu:~/Desktop$ ./spoon.o 
3
RC3
6
te= 0 i= 0 j= 0te= 0 i= 0 j= 1
```

The control directly asks for value for j=1 and j=0 is skipped.WHY?

Comment: You shouldn't be compiling your executable files with `.o` extensions. The `.o` is used to denote an object file.

Comment: Note that `fflush(stdin)` is only really defined on Windows (though the Linux manual page does reference the possibility too, but it is not clear that it actually works).  The C standard leaves it undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fflush(stdin)` is not the way to clear your input buffer.
Use:

```
void flushInputBuffer( void )
{
    int c;
    while( (c = fgetc( stdin )) != EOF && c != '\n' );
}
```

Comment: Your answer is totally right, however could you name your function something other than `fflushstdin`? ;p. This isn't what a flush operation does, so maybe a name like `drain` or something would be better.

Answer (score 1):

This is because `getchar()` still sees the newline that you typed after `6`, so it doesn't need to block and wait for more input from you. I imagine that `getchar()` isn't the function you need to be calling.

Answer (score 0):

Passing stdin to fflush() is incorrect. It should only be used on an output stream.

It's not clear to me from your output, but if you typed 3<enter>6<enter> at the RC prompt, the first getchar() is grabbing the newline you typed at the end of that line.

Try changing this line:

```
    scanf("%d %d",&r, &c);
```

To this:

```
    scanf("%d %d\n",&r, &c);
```

Answer (score -1):

Refer your `C program` with [LIVE Demo](http://ideone.com/L0Bnm)